# Git simplify-by-decoration with decorate-refs-exclude

Tags: git

I'm working in a git (v2.19.1) repo with lots of tags and branches. To get a glance of the git tree, I'd like to use the `--simplify-by-decoration` option while excluding some of the tags with `--decorate-refs-exclude=<pattern>` of `git log`, but, as per [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/2.22.0#Documentation/git-log.txt---simplify-by-decoration):

> --simplify-by-decoration
>
> ```
> Commits that are referred by some branch or tag are selected.
> ```

Thus every tags are selected even those that are excluded from the decoration by the pattern.

Thus, when I enter

```
git log --oneline --graph  --decorate=full --decorate-refs-exclude='refs/tags/<pattern>'
```

The selected tags are properly excluded but once I add the `simplify-by-decoration` option

```
git log --oneline --graph  --decorate=full --decorate-refs-exclude='refs/tags/<pattern>' --simplify-by-decoration
```

The excluded tags pop back again.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: There is no workaround. I'd recommend reporting this as a bug: it seems clear that `--decorate-refs-exclude` should affect which refs are used for `--simplify-by-decoration`.

Comment: @torek I've submitted the bug to git's mailing list. They are actively working on a patch. I'll post an answer as soon as the fix is included in a future release. Thanks!

Comment: For reference: discussed in https://public-inbox.org/git/D941A96E-E5A8-4C86-A200-0BECA30216D1@voucoux.fr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug submitted by the [OP Vser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2622010/vser) should be fixed in Git 2.24 (Q4 2019)

See [commit 0cc7380](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cc7380d8846c30ce0d5d6310b2cb5994f269133), [commit b4ecbcf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b4ecbcf6a256e533a3e0231095758527999e7fe0) (08 Sep 2019) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ed68228](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed6822896bf4d28c12614e18e3fdcc5dc27ff8e5), 07 Oct 2019)</sup>

Before Git 2.24, a decoration filter given with `--decorate-refs-exclude` is inadvertently overruled by `--simplify-by-decoration`.

> ### `log-tree`: call `load_ref_decorations()` in `get_name_decoration()`
>
> Load a default set of ref name decorations at the first lookup.
>   This frees direct and indirect callers from doing so.
>   They can still do it if they want to use a filter or are interested in full decorations
>   instead of the default short ones -- the first `load_ref_decorations()` call wins.
>
> This means that the load in `builtin/log.c::cmd_log_init_finish()` is respected even if `--simplify-by-decoration` is given, as the previously dominating earlier load in `handle_revision_opt()` is gone.
>   So a filter given with `--decorate-refs-exclude` is used for simplification in that
>   case, as expected.